# Possibility to get a matching question completely wrong?

Tags: probability

Say we have a matching question with 10 sub-questions and 10 options. Someone with absolutely no idea what he's doing has $\frac{!10}{10!}\approx0.368$ chance of getting everything wrong.

Now let's say we have 12 options that need to go into 10 sub-questions. What is the chance that he guesses it completely wrong in this case?

Edit: Guesses do not repeat, meaning there are two unused options in the second case.

Comment: Derangements: a permutation of a set, such that no elements are in its original position. !10 = 1,334,961

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  For the first problem, you might have intended to add that the test taker never repeats a guess (that extra assumption would make your formula correct).  But for the second question, that assumption isn't possible.  Therefore, I'd say the naive answer was $\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^{12}$  but perhaps you meant to add the assumption that the test taker never repeats a guess more than $3$ times? Or maybe that they never repeat a guess more than twice and only two guesses may be repeated twice? Or something else?

Comment: Guesses do not repeat, one option goes into one sub-question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ah, I had the roles reversed.  So there are two options which are unused?  I suggest editing your post for clarity.

Comment: It's done, thank you.

Comment: The same logic used for the derangements formula works here.  Apply inclusion-exclusion to find the probability at least one of the correct answers were given in the correct spot.  The problem where the number of answers is the same as the number of spots happens to be such an important counting problem that it receives its own notation, however that doesn't make this second version of the question any more difficult when approached from first principles.

Comment: Two suggestions;  First, you can go through the calculation of the number of derangements and set up a similar recursion for your problem.  Alternatively, you can divide into cases (according to how many of the fake options are used by the test taker).  I'm not sure that the second method actually avoids the first, though.